# How to get a random row from database in more optimized way

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hi i know how to get random row but i need an optimized way, i am migrating huge data from one schema to another in oracle.Other than performing **count** validation on each table. I am doing random record validation (for any random row , i am checking whether all column values match or not between the databases).I am using

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM  ADM_USER ORDER BY dbms_random.value) WHERE rownum = 1;
```

Before that i was using:

```
 select * from ADM_USER where ADM_USER_ID=(select Round(dbms_random.value(1,max(ADM_USER_ID))) from ADM_USER)
```

The problem with the latter one is that values in ADM_USER_ID are not contiguous.So most of the times the query returns empty result set. The first one is good but for tables with huge cardinality it takes 6 to 7 seconnds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ADM_USER where ADM_USER_ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ADM_USER_ID FROM  ADM_USER ORDER BY dbms_random.value);`

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: SELECT TOP(1) ... ORDER BY NEWID()

Comment: @artm,@Biscuits, TOP is neither Oracle nor MySQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Oracle, look at the SAMPLE clause. The following will look at random 1% of a table

```
select * from MDSYS.SDO_COORD_REF_SYS sample(1);
```

You can still add the `rownum=1` filter on top of that.